# Filling RadGridView from DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I need to create a datasource for gridView programmaticlly, so I'm building a DataTable and then assign it to radGridView datasource. First I added the columns using this code for a number of times that matches columns count:

```
    static DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
   List<string> col = new List<string>();
    col.Add("ColumnName");
    dt.Columns.Add("ColumnName");
```

I'm creating a RadGridView rows dynamically using this code:

```
          DataRow d = dt.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < col.Count; i++)
                d[col[i]] = "Shaza";
            dt.Rows.Add(d);
            this.radGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

but the radGridView has the exact count of rows but without any data, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the ASP.NET grid, FWIW: Have you added a Columns() call to the gridview itself?

```
  .Columns(col =>
    {
        col.Bound(p => p.ColumnName).Width(100);
    })
```

Comment: And the columns appear just fine, but no rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is: `this.radGridView1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;`